# Linkedin API for android getConnectionsfor currentuser() exception

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am using linkedin api for android linkedin-j-android.jar.

Through this i can login to my account from my android app and  `client.getProfileForCurrentUser();` and `client.updateCurrentStatus("Status updated from android app");` also works fine.

The problem i am facing is that whenever i make a call to 
`client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser();` or
`Connections connections = client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser(connectionFields);` ,i get exception `"Access to connections denied"`. How to provide the permissions or is there any other way to solve it? i m stuck on here. help me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this api for `linkedIn`. It helps me to post status and get contacts.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

Comment: Thanks for your help. i need some more help. i have tested the sample project. i just want to know how to get logged out from linked in account. every time i run project it does not ask me for username and password and logged me in directly despite of i signed out. Thankyou

Comment: I think android webview database saves your username and password and it checks you in. The only way should be to clear the app data from settings.

Comment: thnx alot. you really helped me alot.

Comment: I also want to get skills, this api does not provide it. Can u plz help me for that