# LinkedInApiClientException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MOBILE

Tags: android, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using linkedin-j-android.jar for linkedinIn connectivity and successfully done my requirement. But for some user, i am getting  below exception when I trying to get user updates.

```
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MOBILE
```

or

```
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SKYPE
```

Below is stack trace:

```
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MOBILE
10-18 11:35:23.166: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiXppClient.unmarshallObject(LinkedInApiXppClient.java:119)
10-18 11:35:23.166: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.readResponse(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:1905)
10-18 11:35:23.166: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.getUserUpdates(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:920)
10-18 11:35:23.166: W/System.err(5813):     at com.tekriti.ice.util.LinkedinUtil.getUserUpdate(LinkedinUtil.java:205)
10-18 11:35:23.166: W/System.err(5813):     at com.tekriti.ice.util.SocialUtil.getAllSocialData(SocialUtil.java:534)
10-18 11:35:23.166: W/System.err(5813):     at com.tekriti.ice.util.SocialUtil$UpdateData.doInBackground(SocialUtil.java:648)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.tekriti.ice.util.SocialUtil$UpdateData.doInBackground(SocialUtil.java:1)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MOBILE
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.PhoneType.fromValue(PhoneType.java:58)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.xpp.PhoneNumberImpl.init(PhoneNumberImpl.java:64)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.xpp.PhoneNumbersImpl.init(PhoneNumbersImpl.java:66)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.xpp.PersonImpl.init(PersonImpl.java:595)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.xpp.UpdateContentImpl.init(UpdateContentImpl.java:128)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.xpp.UpdateImpl.init(UpdateImpl.java:155)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.xpp.UpdatesImpl.init(UpdatesImpl.java:89)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.xpp.NetworkImpl.init(NetworkImpl.java:71)
10-18 11:35:23.174: W/System.err(5813):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiXppClient.unmarshallObject(LinkedInApiXppClient.java:115)
```

Comment: Check this link for good api

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741204/linkedin-api-for-android-getconnectionsfor-currentuser-exception

Comment: @vineet your link is another option to use social network integration. Actually i want to figure out this problem because my application having issue for some linkedin user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error got resolved after creating a new API key on LinkedIn.
New API creation follow the scope to use user data.
See below link for more details
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

So you need to add scope parameter in your authentication request like

https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress