# Linkedin authentication using oauth 2.0

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to integrate Linkedin with android app using oauth 2.0 authentication.The Linkedin Dev site says recently they started supporting oauth 2.0.But couldn't find a way to add it to my application.If anyone had done this before please guide me.

Comment: https://github.com/tnj/AndroidOAuthExample example of oauth 2.0

Comment: @Richa: is that for LI authentication? Well the application is in Japanese language so i couldn't understand anything.

Comment: Check this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741204/linkedin-api-for-android-getconnectionsfor-currentuser-exception/12741610#12741610

Comment: For Linkedin Oauth2.0,Check the right answer of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/22062145/2219600