# LinkedIn Rest API, State token doesn't match

Tags: android, android-webview, token, linkedin-api, state

I am referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062145/oauth-2-0-authorization-for-linkedin-in-android/22219383#22219383) to authorize, authenticate and login to LinkedIn account using Rest API, but now i am facing problem, the WebView where i am displaying the LinkedIn Rest API call url view, is returning blank with message as "**State token doesn't match**"

It was working fine earlier, but now its returning blank view.

What might be the solution to this? Thanks and help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkedIn locked many parts of its APIs on May 12, 2015 according to https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

What you're trying to do probably cannot be done anymore following their new API updates.

Comment: Karim, i read the above mentioned post, and i have implemented using new provided methods, but from yesterday night its gone

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to know that LinkedIn API is not providing permissions for getting user full profile information, the permissions at developers console are being managed by them and for further API requests or data, you have to request a form to LinkedIn.

Right away i have integrated both Rest API and Android sdk into my application for login and share

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem and all i did is i removed the full profile permission from the REST API call. Now its working fine

Before:

```
private static final String SCOPES = "r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_network";
```

Now:

```
private static final String SCOPES = "r_basicprofile";
```

Check out follwoing document and use the basic profile fields appropriately:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields