# Issue with linkedIn integration with Android App

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am developing an android app and i want to use the linkedIn signIn.
I have followed the tuto [Oauth 2.0 authorization for LinkedIn in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062145/oauth-2-0-authorization-for-linkedin-in-android)...
I get the access token but i can't find a way to the next step to get Profile Data.PLease can u help me!

Answer (score 0):

[Android Mobile SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk)

[LinkedIn API Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)

Use official LinkedIn `android mobile sdk`.following codes will do the job for you for fetching detalis by using `android mobile sdk`

> **Constants.java**

```
        public static final String HOST = "api.linkedin.com";
        public static final String FETCH_BASIC_INFO = "https://" + HOST + "/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry)";
        public static final String FETCH_CONTACT_INFO = "https://" + HOST + "/v1/people/~:(num-connections,email-address,phone-numbers,main-address)";
        public static final String FETCH_PROFILE_PICTURE = "https://" + HOST + "/v1/people/~:(picture-urls::(original))";
        public static final String SHARE_POST = "https://" + HOST + "/v1/people/~/shares";
```

> **You can call the API's as follows after successfull login**

```
APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

        apiHelper.getRequest(MainActivity.this, Constants.FETCH_BASIC_INFO, new ApiListener() {
            @Override
            public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse s) {

                    String response = apiResponse.toString()



            }

            @Override
            public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {

               String errorCode= error.toString()


            }
        });
```

> **Do not forget to set client side permissions**

```
/*Set LinkedIn permission for fetch info */
    private static Scope buildScope() {
        return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.R_CONTACTINFO);
    }
```

> **You can post to LinkedIn using following snippet**

```
public void postRequest(String shareUrl, String shareJsonText) {
        APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(context);
        apiHelper.postRequest(activity, shareUrl, shareJsonText, new ApiListener() {
            @Override
            public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
                String response = apiResponse.toString()

            }

            @Override
            public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {
                 String errorCode= error.toString()
            }
        });
    }
```

> **Call the method**

```
String shareJsonText = "{ \n" +
                        "   \"comment\":\"" + shareComment.getText() + " About our company : Codelynks is a provider of software solutions provider for leading companies round the globe. Codelynks is exclusively into helping the clients manage the ..." + "\"," +
                        "   \"visibility\":{ " +
                        "      \"code\":\"anyone\"" +
                        "   }," +
                        "   \"content\":{ " +
                        "      \"title\":\"Test Share Title\"," +
                        "      \"description\":\"Codelynks - Inspired Innovations\"," +
                        "      \"submitted-url\":\"http://www.codelynks.com/\"," +
                        "      \"submitted-image-url\":\"http://m3.licdn.com/media/p/3/000/124/1a6/089a29a.png\"" +
                        "   }" +
                        "}";


      postRequest(Constants.SHARE_POST, shareJsonText);
```