# Linkedin login android SDK access token is not set

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I implement LinkedIn Register in to my android app... I use LinkedIn Android SDK: 
[link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth) and i follow these tutorial: [tut](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-linkedin-integration-login-tutorial/)
However I stuck in one big problem. I successful get token by method:

```
LISessionManager.getInstance(getContext()).init(mLoginActivity, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
```

And after it i try to make APIHelper request to get profile data:

```
       APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getContext());
                            apiHelper.getRequest(mLoginActivity, topCardUrl, new ApiListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse s) {
```

But every time i try to get profile data i get following result:
exceptionMsg: access toke is not set
How can i fix it? I can't understand where is problem. Please help.

Comment: I notice that, boolean accessTokenValid = LISessionManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getSession().isValid(); return me false, however LISessionManager.getInstance(mLoginActivity).getSession().getAccessToken() return json with accessTokenValue... Maybe it's important point...

Comment: Hello @SebastianK, Is this issue resolved? currently i am facing same issue. kindly please share the solution.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue :( Any update ?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue :(

Comment: hi, I am also facing the same problem.is this resolved??

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. so please let me know whenever you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Linkedin currently stopped support for Mobile SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth) that's why all started getting access token is not set.

For more information https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

Alternate to achieve the same in Android by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22219383

Answer (score -2):

```
public void login(){

 LISessionManager.getInstance(getActivity()).init(getActivity(),

buildScope(), new AuthListener()
{
 @Override
  public void onAuthSuccess() 
   {

  progress.show();
  getUserData();
    }
 @Override
 public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {

      if(progress.isShowing())
        progress.dismiss();
            }

            }, false);
}
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
String u="https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-    name,headline,picture-url,public_profile_url,industry,summary,specialties,picture-urls::(original),positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes),associations,interests,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,publications:(id,title,publisher:(name),authors:(id,name),date,url,summary),patents:(id,title,summary,number,status:(id,name),office:(name),inventors:(id,name),date,url),languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name)),skills:(id,skill:(name)),certifications:(id,name,authority:(name),number,start-date,end-date),courses:(id,name,number),recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender),honors-awards,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,volunteer)";

public void getUserData() 
{
 APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
 apiHelper.getRequest(getActivity(), u, new ApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse result) {
            try {
               //progress.dismiss();
                socialData = new SocialLoginBean();
                JSONObject json = result.getResponseDataAsJson();
                String fname = json.getString("firstName");
                String lname = json.getString("lastName");
                socialData.setFname(fname);
                socialData.setLname(lname);
                JSONObject pic = json.getJSONObject("pictureUrls");
                JSONArray picarr = pic.getJSONArray("values");
                profile_pic = picarr.getString(0);
                socialData.setPictureUrl(profile_pic);
                JSONObject obj =       json.getJSONObject("positions").getJSONArray("values").getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject positions = obj.getJSONObject("company");
 String companyDesc="",companyName="",industry="",jobTitle="";
       if(obj.has("title"))
           jobTitle = obj.getString("title");

       if(obj.has("summary"))
           companyDesc = obj.getString("summary");

       if(positions.has("name"))
           companyName = positions.getString("name");

       if(json.has("industry"))
          industry = json.getString("industry");

 String publicProfileUrl = json.getString("publicProfileUrl");

                socialData.setProfileUrl(publicProfileUrl);
                socialData.setIndustry(industry);
                socialData.setCompany(companyName);
                socialData.setDesignation(jobTitle);
                socialData.setCompanyDescription(companyDesc);

                moveTo(socialData);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                if(progress.isShowing())
                    progress.dismiss();
                moveTo(socialData);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {
            if(progress.isShowing())
                progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```