# How to login and post with LinkedIn if LinkedIn native app is not installed in android?

Tags: android, post, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to login and post image on linkedIn from my android application. I am using code posted here by AmalBit :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22219383/5707364

Now i want to post image on LinkedIn . How can i do so **using oauth2**?

Or is it possible to post image on LinkedIn using **LinkedIn SDK**? 
If LinkedIn native app is installed, All working great using LinkedIn SDK, but what if **LinkedIn native app is not installed**?
Ref: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can use their REST API, please use the below reference

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api